# Detect a pressed-down hover on a component

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

In Android Jetpack Compose, how can we detect a hover over another widget if the gesture is actually pressed down? I can find the bounds of a Circular or a rectangular component by finding the global position of the component, but I am not able to find the exact bounds of a custom shaped widget (consider a start shaped widget)

```
@Composable
fun WidgetWithBounds(
    content: @Composable () -> Unit,
    onBoundsUpdated: BoundsUpdateListener,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    isHovered: Boolean = false,
) {
    val componentBounds = remember { mutableStateOf(Rect.Zero) }
    var boxSize by remember {
        mutableStateOf(IntSize.Zero)
    }
    var boxOffset by remember {
        mutableStateOf(Offset.Zero)
    }

    Box(modifier = Modifier


        .onGloballyPositioned { coordinates ->
            val globalPosition = coordinates.positionInRoot()
            boxOffset = globalPosition
            componentBounds.value = Rect(
                left = boxOffset.x,
                top = boxOffset.y,
                right = boxOffset.x + boxSize.width,
                bottom = boxOffset.y + boxSize.height
            )
            onBoundsUpdated.update(componentBounds.value)
        }
        .onSizeChanged {
            boxSize = it
            componentBounds.value = Rect(
                left = boxOffset.x,
                top = boxOffset.y,
                right = boxOffset.x + boxSize.width,
                bottom = boxOffset.y + boxSize.height
            )
            onBoundsUpdated.update(componentBounds.value)

        }
        .then(modifier)) {
        // Your component content
    }
}
```

This provides only a Rectangular bound of the widget and can compare the X-offset and Y-offset of MotionEvent with it. But I cannot find any way to find the exact bounds of custom shaped widget for example a Star or a Triangle